# Migrating from EF Core 2 to EF Core 3 - Datetime milliseconds precision

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have some migrations which insert some data into the database and this is one of them:

```
 migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "TSegment",
            columns: new[] { "SegmentId", "CreatedOn", "ParentId", "SegmentType", "UpdatedOn" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
                { 1, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(4948), null, "YouAndYourFamily", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(5782) },
                { 2, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6649), 1, "AboutYou", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6658) },
                { 3, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6670), 1, "YourFamily", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6676) },
                { 4, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6679), 1, "Employment", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6685) },
                { 5, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6688), null, "HomeAndContact", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6694) },
                { 6, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6700), 5, "YourHome", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6703) },
                { 7, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6709), 5, "ContactDetails", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, 48, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(6712) }
            });
```

After upgrading EF Core to version 3 the code above generates this insert:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] ON;
INSERT INTO [TSegment] ([SegmentId], [CreatedOn], [ParentId], [SegmentType], [UpdatedOn])
VALUES (1, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0484948Z', NULL, N'YouAndYourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0485782Z'),
(2, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486649Z', 1, N'AboutYou', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486658Z'),
(3, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486670Z', 1, N'YourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486676Z'),
(4, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486679Z', 1, N'Employment', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486685Z'),
(5, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486688Z', NULL, N'HomeAndContact', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486694Z'),
(6, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486700Z', 5, N'YourHome', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486703Z'),
(7, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486709Z', 5, N'ContactDetails', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0486712Z');
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] OFF;
```

As we can see, the dates milliseconds have 6 decimal places, but if I downgrade EF Core to version 2, the same migration generates this insert:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] ON;
INSERT INTO [TSegment] ([SegmentId], [CreatedOn], [ParentId], [SegmentType], [UpdatedOn])
VALUES (1, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', NULL, N'YouAndYourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(2, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', 1, N'AboutYou', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(3, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', 1, N'YourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(4, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', 1, N'Employment', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(5, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', NULL, N'HomeAndContact', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(6, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', 5, N'YourHome', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048'),
(7, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048', 5, N'ContactDetails', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.048');
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] OFF;
```

As SQL Server has a precision of 3 decimal places and I can't change all datetime columns to `Datetime2`, does anyone know a workaround for it?

---

Well, the problem is not really the milliseconds. I removed `AddTicks` and also milliseconds from my migration:

```
  migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "TSegment",
            columns: new[] { "SegmentId", "CreatedOn", "ParentId", "SegmentType", "UpdatedOn" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
                { 1, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), null, "YouAndYourFamily", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                { 2, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), 1, "AboutYou", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc)},
                { 3, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), 1, "YourFamily", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                { 4, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), 1, "Employment", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                { 5, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), null, "HomeAndContact", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                { 6, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), 5, "YourHome", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                { 7, new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc), 5, "ContactDetails", new DateTime(2019, 1, 22, 12, 24, 23,DateTimeKind.Utc) }
            });
```

Which now generates the following script:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] ON;
INSERT INTO [TSegment] ([SegmentId], [CreatedOn], [ParentId], [SegmentType], [UpdatedOn])
VALUES (1, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', NULL, N'YouAndYourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(2, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', 1, N'AboutYou', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(3, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', 1, N'YourFamily', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(4, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', 1, N'Employment', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(5, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', NULL, N'HomeAndContact', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(6, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', 5, N'YourHome', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z'),
(7, '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z', 5, N'ContactDetails', '2019-01-22T12:24:23.0000000Z');
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'SegmentId', N'CreatedOn', N'ParentId', N'SegmentType', N'UpdatedOn') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[TSegment]'))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TSegment] OFF;
```

It still generates 6 decimal places for milliseconds and this expcetion is being thrown:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed
> when converting date and/or time from character string.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
> methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
> completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache,
> Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
> connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
> migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade
> databaseFacade)    at
> IntelliFlo.Platform.EntityFramework.Database.Tasks.DatabaseMigrationTask.Run()
> at
> IntelliFlo.Platform.EntityFramework.Database.DatabaseInitializer.ExecuteTask(IDatabaseTask
> task)

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the table column type?There's no point in storing microseconds when the column is a `datetime2(0)` or `datetime2(3)`.

Comment: BTW why are you using *ticks*? Do you really want to save microseconds? In that case you'll have to use the appropriate type. `datetime` doesn't have the required precision. You'd have to use `datetime2(7)` *and* specify that precision in the column annotation. Even then, you'd get a 100ns accuracy

Comment: After reading the question twice, I'm confused. If you only want *milliseconds*, using ticks is pointless. In fact, EF Core 2's truncation should be treated as a *bug* - `datetime` [doesn't even have millisecond precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision). You can get either `.047` or `.050`. All of those values would be stored as `.050` in the database. Do you have an actual problem? Or did you depend in the buggy implementation to get `.047` instead of `.050` ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve your issue by wrapping it in a [sqlDataTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlDateTime__ctor_System_DateTime_) struct like:

```cs
new SqlDateTime (DateTime value)
```

if it's a poco object:
You can try specifying the column type with a data anontations like this

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
```

see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-data-types)

Comment: This won't help. The values the OP wants to store *can't* be stored using `datetime` and will be rounded to either `.047` or `.050`. Even `.048` will be rounded to `.047`. EF Core 2's truncation is actually a bug